# Android speech recognition and webrtc communication at the same time

Tags: android, speech-recognition, webrtc, audio-streaming

My application offers a **webrtc communication** with audio and video stream and I want add a speech recognition using **android.speech API**. The speech recognition works perfectly at the beginning. But at the very moment I publish a stream with webrtc, the speech recognition doesn't work anymore, I get an **ERROR_CLIENT** from SpeechRecognizer each time I start to listen. And when I close the webrtc connection, it works again.

I think that I can't use speech recognition because the audio stream has already been use by webrtc. Is there a way to duplicate the audio stream and specify a voice input source to speech recognition?